# How to get the Disk Image property using terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, metadata

Let's say I have the volume path.
Normally I can right-click and 'Get info' to get its Disk image.
I want to replicate the same on terminal (basically need to code it in objective C)
mdls doesn't seem to helping. Not xattr, putils etc.

Comment: Most of the data found in the GetInfo window is filesystem metadata. From the command line you can use `stat` , the only info missing would be the `Where:` label which you can use `hdiutil info`.

Answer (score 1):

The Disk Utility application shows the following on my Mac.

[image: w1]

If I select "Get Info" on Marlin, I get the following popup.

[image: w2]

I can also get information about the volume labeled `Marlin` by entering the following command in a Terminal application window.

```
diskutil  info  Marlin
```

Doing so produces the following output.

```
   Device Identifier:        disk0s4
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0s4
   Whole:                    No
   Part of Whole:            disk0

   Volume Name:              Marlin
   Mounted:                  Yes
   Mount Point:              /

   Partition Type:           Apple_HFS
   File System Personality:  Journaled HFS+
   Type (Bundle):            hfs
   Name (User Visible):      Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
   Journal:                  Journal size 24576 KB at offset 0x64fa5000
   Owners:                   Enabled

   OS Can Be Installed:      Yes
   Booter Disk:              disk0s5
   Recovery Disk:            disk0s5
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 SATA
   SMART Status:             Verified
   Volume UUID:              E0633113-8178-33A2-8ADF-95B61C49FD19
   Disk / Partition UUID:    398EA755-F8F5-403B-B946-0C75B5AD2783
   Partition Offset:         149075562496 Bytes (291163208 512-Byte-Device-Blocks)

   Disk Size:                250.0 GB (249999994880 Bytes) (exactly 488281240 512-Byte-Units)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Volume Total Space:       250.0 GB (249999994880 Bytes) (exactly 488281240 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Used Space:        237.4 GB (237416558592 Bytes) (exactly 463704216 512-Byte-Units) (95.0%)
   Volume Free Space:        12.6 GB (12583436288 Bytes) (exactly 24577024 512-Byte-Units) (5.0%)
   Allocation Block Size:    4096 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         No

   Device Location:          Internal
   Removable Media:          Fixed

   Solid State:              No
   Hardware AES Support:     No
```

Which is basically the same as using the Disk Utility application.